# Extract string before "|"

Tags: r, extract, substr

I have a data set wherein a column looks like this:

```
ABC|DEF|GHI,  
ABCD|EFG|HIJK,  
ABCDE|FGHI|JKL,  
DEF|GHIJ|KLM,  
GHI|JKLM|NO|PQRS,  
BCDE|FGHI|JKL
```

.... and so on

I need to extract the characters that appear before the first `|` symbol.

In Excel, we would use a combination of MID-SEARCH or a LEFT-SEARCH, R contains `substr()`.

The syntax is - `substr(x, <start>,<stop>)`

In my case, start will always be 1. For stop, we need to search by `|`. How can we achieve this? Are there alternate ways to do this?

Comment: `?regexpr` returns the index of the first match that can be used as your "stop" argument -- `regexpr("|", x, fixed = TRUE) - 1`

Answer (score 71):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("\\|.*", "", str1)
#[1] "ABC"
```

Or with `strsplit`

```
strsplit(str1, "[|]")[[1]][1]
#[1] "ABC"
```

#### Update

If we use the data from @hrbrmstr

```
sub("\\|.*", "", df$V1)
#[1] "ABC"   "ABCD"  "ABCDE" "DEF"   "GHI"   "BCDE"
```

These are all base R methods.  No external packages used.

#### data

```
str1 <- "ABC|DEF|GHI ABCD|EFG|HIJK ABCDE|FGHI|JKL DEF|GHIJ|KLM GHI|JKLM|NO|PQRS BCDE|FGHI|JKL"
```

Answer (score 26):

Another option `word` function of `stringr` package

```
library(stringr)
word(df1$V1,1,sep = "\\|")
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "ABC|DEF|GHI,  
ABCD|EFG|HIJK,  
ABCDE|FGHI|JKL,  
DEF|GHIJ|KLM,  
GHI|JKLM|NO|PQRS,  
BCDE|FGHI|JKL")
```

Comment: I especially like this package's ability to get, for example, the first two "words".

Comment: so simple - thank you!

Answer (score 5):

with `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)

df <- read.table(text="ABC|DEF|GHI,1
ABCD|EFG|HIJK,2
ABCDE|FGHI|JKL,3  
DEF|GHIJ|KLM,4
GHI|JKLM|NO|PQRS,5
BCDE|FGHI|JKL,6", sep=",", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

stri_match_first_regex(df$V1, "(.*?)\\|")[,2]
## [1] "ABC"   "ABCD"  "ABCDE" "DEF"   "GHI"   "BCDE"
```