# Substring match when filtering rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have strings in file1 that matches part of the strings in file2. I want to filter out the strings from file2 that partly matches those in file1. Please see my try. Not sure how to define substring match in this way.

file1:

```
V1
species1
species121
species14341
```

file2

```
V1
genus1|species1|strain1
genus1|species121|strain1
genus1|species1442|strain1
genus1|species4242|strain1
genus1|species4131|strain1
```

my try:

```
file1[!file1$V1 %in% file2$V1]
```

Comment: You could try to read in both files as dataframes and **fuzzy join** those (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+fuzzy+join+dataframes). Choose the appropriate join direction to keep only matching rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `%in%` operator in this way in R. It is used to determine whether an element of a vector is in another vector, not like `in` in Python which can be used to match a substring: Look at this:

```r
"species1" %in% "genus1|species1|strain1" # FALSE
"species1" %in% c("genus1", "species1", "strain1") # TRUE
```

You can, however, use `grepl` for this (the `l` is for logical, i.e. it returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`).

```r
grepl("species1", "genus1|species1|strain1") # TRUE
```

There's an additional complication here in that you cannot use `grepl` with a vector, as it will only compare the first value:

```r
grepl(file1$V1, "genus1|species1|strain1") 
[1] TRUE
Warning message:
In grepl(file1$V1, "genus1|species1|strain1") :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

The above simply tells you that the first element of `file1$V1` is in `"genus1|species1|strain1"`.

Furthermore, you want to compare each element in `file1$V1` to an entire vector of strings, rather than just one string. That's OK but you will get a vector the same length as the second vector as an output:

```r
grepl("species1", file2$V1) 
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

We can just see if `any()` of those are a match. As you've tagged your question with `tidyverse`, here's a `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
 file1 |>
    rowwise() |> # This makes sure you only pass one element at a time to `grepl`
    mutate(
        in_v2 = any(grepl(V1, file2$V1)) 
    ) |>
    filter(!in_v2)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
# Rowwise: 
#   V1           in_v2
#   <chr>        <lgl>
# 1 species14341 FALSE
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant opposite. Want to remove from file2, the elements found in file1. I guess just switching the filenames works

Comment: Yes exactly - it's the same principle

Comment: @user2300940 You could also just do `file2[!sapply(file2$V1, \(x) any(grepl(x, file1$V1))),]`, provided that genus names are always separated by `|`, as this acts as the OR operator in regex. Incidentally feel free to accept either this answer or the one by @R18 - I think either is an acceptable approach.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get what you want is using the `grepl` function. So, you can run the following code:

```
# Load library
  library(qdapRegex)
# Extract the names of file2$V1 you are interested in (those between | |)
  v <- unlist(rm_between(file2$V1, "|", "|", extract = T))
# Which of theese elements are in file1$V1?
  elem.are <- which(v %in% file1$V1)
# Delete the elements in elem.are
  file2$V1[-elem.are]
```

1. In `v` we save the names of `file2$V1` we are interested in (those
   between | |)
2. Then we save at `elem.are` the positions of those names which appear
   in `file1$V1`
3. Finally, we omit those elements using  `file2$V1[-elem.are]`

Comment: Sorry, I meant opposite. Want to remove from file2, the elements found in file1. I guess just switching the filenames works

Comment: Although the change in your approach is samll, the code changes a lot. I have edited my message, and now I think it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks. What I am interested in the names also before | in file2?

Comment: Then, instead of `unlist(rm_between(file2$V1, "|", "|", extract = T))` you should write something like any of the answers in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291794/extract-string-before